# works in ie9 and ff4 - not in ie7 or ie 8?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I wrote this script awhile back and have modified it to use css sprites to cut down on images.  Everything works perfect in ie9 and ff4, however, I noticed it will not show in ie7/ie8... It must be a css or js problem, but I certainly cannot see anything that would be preventing the older ie's from displaying the code...

I have included the entire contents below in a 'test' page which includes everything... if someone can point me out to why this is not working in ie7 or ie8 I would be very grateful!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">    
#social16 {height:16px;font-size:13px; color:#0066ff; font-weight:bold;}
#sb16 {margin: 0px; padding:0px; height:16px; display: inline;line-height:16px;}
#sb16 li {list-style-type:none;float:left;padding:0 5px 0 0;}
#sb16 li a {background:url(social.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;display: block;height: 16px;width:16px;}
#sb16 li a.item0 {background-position:0px 0px;}
#sb16 li a.item1 {background-position:-16px 0px;}
#sb16 li a.item2 {background-position:-32px 0px;}
#sb16 li a.item3 {background-position:-48px 0px;}
#sb16 li a.item4 {background-position:-64px 0px;}
#sb16 li a.item5 {background-position:-80px 0px;}
#sb16 li a.item6 {background-position:-96px 0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="social16"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){

var sites = [
        ['Send to Facebook', 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}&amp;t={title}'],
        ['Tweet This', 'http://twitter.com/share?text={title}&amp;url={url}'],
        ['Send to StumbleUpon', 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url={url}&amp;title={title}'],
        ['Digg This', 'http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&amp;url={url}&amp;title={title}'],
        ['Send to GoogleBuzz', 'http://www.google.com/buzz/post?message={title}&amp;url={url}'],        
        ['Send to Reddit', 'http://reddit.com/submit?url={url}&amp;title={title}'],
        ['Email to Friends', 'mailto:?subject={title}&amp;body={url}'],
    ];

var url = encodeURIComponent(location.href),
    url = url.replace( "#", "" ),
    title = encodeURIComponent(document.title),
    html = '<ul id="sb16"><li>Share this ... </li>';

for (var i = 0, len = sites.length; i < len; i++) {
    var site = sites[i],
    link = site[1].replace('{url}', url).replace('{title}', title);

    html += '<li><a class="item' + i + '" href="#" title="' + site[0] + '" onclick="window.open(\'' + link + '\')"></a></li>';
}

html += '</ul>';

document.getElementById("social16").innerHTML=(html);

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or at least a live link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma after the last element of `sites`:

```
var sites = [
    //...
    ['Email to Friends', 'mailto:?subject={title}&amp;body={url}'],
    // -----------------------------------------------------------^
];
```

IE6 and IE7 don't like that. This usually shows up as a `null` at the end of the array and you end up with a `null` where you don't expect one.

Comment: rofl - that was it - I've been staring at this for a few hours it seems and thats all it was... never noticed it... thanks!

Comment: @user756659: That's the first thing to look for when "it works in *X* but not in IE6 or IE7". Anyway, alex got in first so you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sites = [
        ...
        ['Email to Friends', 'mailto:?subject={title}&amp;body={url}'],
    ];
```

Your last element has a trailing `,`. Remove it.

[Further Reading](http://brajesh.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/internet-explorers-trailing-comma-woes/).

Comment: That's the first thing to look for when you see "works in *X* but not IE6 or IE7".

Comment: @mu That is exactly what I did :)